# NestJS Using ConfigService with TypeOrmModule

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I set up a ConfigService as described in docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

How can I use this service with the the TypeOrmModule?

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

See https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration **Async Configuration** chapter

```js
import { ConfigService } from './config.service'
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('database'),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Few changes were needed to get it to work for me at least:


1. import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
2. imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],

Comment: @Kevin Exactly!

Answer (score 5):

In **NestJS 10.0.0** a superclean way of doing this is as follows:

###### Step 1. Create a `.env` file.

```env
# DATABASE
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=demo-db
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=example
```

###### Step 2. Register your database config using `registerAs`.

```ts
// config/database.config.ts

import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export default registerAs(
  'database',
  (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: true,
  }),
);
```

###### Step 3: Then load this `databaseConfig` into the main `app.module.ts` as follows:

```ts
// app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import databaseConfig from './config/database.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(databaseConfig()),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

###### That's All!

---

Additionally, If you wish to access this `database` configuration in one of your module services, you can do it as below:

```ts
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ load: [databaseConfig] }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(databaseConfig()),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```ts
// [feature].module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  controllers: [FeatureController],
  providers: [FeatureService],
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

```ts
// feature.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class FeatureService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  printConfiguration() {
    console.log(this.configService.get('database'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on @Monfa.red's answer, here's an example of what TypeORMConfigService looks like:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common'
import {ConfigService} from '@nestjs/config'
import {TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory} from '@nestjs/typeorm'

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
    constructor(protected readonly configService: ConfigService) {}
    createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        const {configService} = this
        return {
            type: 'postgres',
            host: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_HOST'),
            port: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_PORT'),
            username: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_USER'),
            password: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
            database: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_DB'),
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: !configService.get('PRODUCTION')
        }
    }
}
```