# NestJs - TypeORM configuration works but not with ConfigService

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I would like to create a REST API with NestJs and TypeORM. In my **app.module.ts** I load the TypeORM module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      database: 'api',
      entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and it's working fine for now. I would like to load the configuration from an external .env file so from the docs

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration

and from here

[NestJS Using ConfigService with TypeOrmModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570212/nestjs-using-configservice-with-typeormmodule)

I created a .env file in the root project directory with the following content

```
DATABASE_TYPE = postgres
DATABASE_HOST = localhost
DATABASE_PORT = 5432
DATABASE_USERNAME = postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD = postgres
DATABASE_NAME = api
DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE = true
```

Next I update my code to

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: configService.get<any>('DATABASE_TYPE'),
        host: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: configService.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'),
        entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
        synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Unfortunately I get this error on startup

```
[Nest] 28257   - 01/06/2020, 7:19:20 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmCoreModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
 +1ms
```

When I log the configuration in my **main.ts** within the **bootstrap** function I get a correct configuration from the .env file.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: add your configService file please

Comment: @ Selmi sorry, I don't have a ConfigService file. I just have to inject it, as you can see in the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of two things needs to happen:

1) You need to make your `ConfigModule` global by passing the `isGlobal: true` option to `ConfigModule.forRoot()`. If you do this, then you can remove the import in the `TypeormModule.forRootAsync()` (it's then a global module and can have it's providers used anywhere)

2) Make another module (`MyConfigModule` or something) that `imports` the `ConfigModule` with its configuration and `exports` the `CofnigModule`. Then you can change `ConfigModule.forRoot()` to `MyConfigModule` in the `AppModule` and you can change `imports: [ConfigModule]` to `imports: [MyConfigModule]` in the `TypeormModule.forRootAsync()` configuration.

Comment: you saved me hours! thx

Answer (score 5):

code translation of @ Jay McDoniel explanation

typeorm.config.ts

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { LoggerOptions } from 'typeorm';

export default class TypeOrmConfig {
  static getOrmConfig(configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: configService.get('DB_HOST') || 'localhost',
      port: configService.get('DB_PORT') || 5432,
      username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
      database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
      entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize:configService.get<boolean>('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE') || false,
      logging: configService.get<LoggerOptions>('TYPEORM_LOGGING') || false
    };
  }
}

export const typeOrmConfigAsync: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => TypeOrmConfig.getOrmConfig(configService),
  inject: [ConfigService]
};
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { ServiceModule } from './service/service.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RedisCacheModule } from './redis-cache/redis-cache.module';
import { typeOrmConfigAsync } from './config/typeorm.config';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(typeOrmConfigAsync),
    UserModule,
    ServiceModule,
    LoginModule,
    RedisCacheModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[nestjs](/questions/tagged/nestjs)[configmodule](/questions/tagged/configmodule)[typeorm](/questions/tagged/typeorm)

[Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDlBnxVzS_Q)
[Reference code](https://github.com/amitavdevzone/nest-js-quiz-manager/blob/master/server/src/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Nestjs-query for graphql, which is this [library](https://github.com/tripss/nestjs-query)

Check the library version, I used 5.0.0-alpha-1, this problem came out. The quick solution is just revert back to version-3.0.0, this problem is solved.