# connection name is deprecated in Typeorm for multiple database connections

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I updated the Typeorm with nestjs and now it shows that connection name is deprecated and we are only able to access one database connection at a time.
[image]

Is there anything new that has been introduced? The nestjs documentation for multiple database connections is still the same

Comment: I think you should look around at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578302/12599279

Comment: @HaiAlison, This explains how I can have different configs for different environments but it does not state how we can have multiple connections in the same environment.

Comment: you mean master slave  connection?

Comment: Not a master-slave but lets say one connection to Psql  other to oracledb.

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM 0.3.0 introduced new connection classes, and they removed the old Connection class which was replaced by DataSource. I think as a result a data source no longer requires a name, but the property was left in the options and marked deprecated. Thus, it's just being ignored for backwards compatability.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/8616

I was able to config multiple databases without using a name and didn't see any issues, but I can't actually find an official statement anywhere on TypeORM about the deprecation of name.